# Promoted In-App purchase not showing in app store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I've recently implemented requires of promoting In-app purchase, I mean `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` delegate, and it's fine and works.

Also my items show up in my app's page in `In-App Purchases` section, but as I see some apps showing one or two items in search page of App Store. Like asphalt:

[image]

My question is:

> what should I do to showing up my IAP in search page of App Store ?

As I noticed the items that show in search page has blue background in app page, And I don't know whats the differences between items with blue background vs items that doesn't have background!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look through the apple document ([link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/promoting-in-app-purchases/)) and found:

> This image appears on your App Store product page; on the Today, Games, and Apps tabs if your content is featured; and can appear in search results. **Please note that only non-consumable in-app purchases will show up in search results.**

and all of my items are consumable, then they won't appear in search result.

Answer (score 1):

It's "new" feature over at [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com). Go to Apps > Your app > Features > App Store Promotions. If you are already using it, you should look for ways to improve your ranking. Specifically check the "Creating Effective Metadata" section in below's doc to improve your ranking.

Official docs: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/promoting-in-app-purchases/